# How do you get while loop to repeat over and over again in Python?

Tags: python

I am having trouble getting my while loop to loop over and over again in Python.  Here is the problem/question I am trying to solve:

Implement the `roll_dice` function in `hog.py`.

- It takes two arguments: a positive integer called `num_rolls` giving the number of dice to roll and a `dice()` function.
- It returns the number of points scored by rolling the dice that number of times in a turn: either the sum of the outcomes or 1 (aka 'Pig Out': If any of the dice outcomes is a 1, the current player's score for the turn is 1).
  To obtain a single outcome of a dice roll, call `dice()`. You should call `dice()` exactly `num_rolls` times in the body of roll_dice. Remember to call `dice()` exactly `num_rolls` times even if 'Pig Out' happens in the middle of rolling. In this way, you correctly simulate rolling all the dice together.

Here is my code so far, where `num_rolls`: the number of dice rolls that will be made and `dice()`: a function that simulates a single dice roll outcome.

```
def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    current_roll = 0
    while current_roll < num_rolls:
        current_roll += 1
        total_sum = 0
        current_value = dice()
        if current_value == 1 or total_sum == 1:
            total_sum = 1
            return total_sum
        else:
            total_sum += current_value
            return total_sum
```

When I debug in PyCharm, in my example when it randomly rolls on current_value = 4, the total sum = 4 and current_roll = 1 even when the required amount of loops is num_rolls = 5. So, meaning that it has only looped once when it should loop 5 times. Could anyone give any insight as to why this might be? I've made a tweak before when `current_value = dice()` was outside the while loop and I moved it inside the while loop and I thought it would fix that but it hasn't.

Also, let me know if there are any clarifications I can make. I am a beginner learner and I'm not great at explaining things

Comment: your function will `return` in either the `if` or `else` statement, which breaks out of the loop. it seems like what you want to do is move your `return total_sum` statement outside of your while loop.

Comment: @L.Grozinger isn't my while loop currently true? since `current_roll = 0` and the while loop only occurs when `current_roll = 0 < num_rolls = 5` which is True

Comment: Your while-loop itself is ok, but you do the return too early. The if-else clause with the return statements should not be indented with the loop, it should only happen after the while-loop has finished.

Comment: @khuynh would deleting the two `return total_sum` statements and only adding only `return total_sum` at the same indentation as the while loop fix this issue?

Comment: BTW, you should use `for _ in range(num_rolls):` rather than a `while` loop.

Comment: @smci does that mean there should only be one `return total_sum` statement? And that would be after the while loop condition is False?

Comment: @Barmar that makes sense - i created a while loop because most of the discussion on my class piazza board used while loops

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you misplaced your final return statement (indentation matters!). This is how it should look:

```
def roll_dice(num_rolls, dice=six_sided):
    current_roll = 0
    total_sum = 0
    while current_roll < num_rolls:
        current_roll += 1
        current_value = dice()
        if current_value == 1:
            total_sum = 1
            break
        else:
            total_sum += current_value
    return total_sum
```

Comment: thank you! It was such a simple mistake but I was stuck on this for hours. I'll know now for the future

Comment: actually, when I run this through my autograder it is failing the last case. I moved the `total_sum = 0` to right under `current_roll = 0` instead of inside the while loop. Here is what is says in my autograder: >>> counted_dice = make_test_dice(4, 1, 2, 6)
>>> roll_dice(3, counted_dice)
1
>>> # Make sure you call dice exactly num_rolls times!
>>> # If you call it fewer or more than that, it won't be at the right spot in the cycle for the next roll
>>> # Note that a return statement in a for loop ends the loop
>>> roll_dice(1, counted_dice)
2
Error: expected 6, got 2

Comment: You are right, my bad. I edited my post and moved total_sum out of the while loop now.